# MySQL: select default row (not default values) if other row not available

Tags: sql, mysql, join, default, fallback

**edit:**

I've included the create statements and a small set of test data for you to try out. Therefor, I've changed the example `id` to `2` in stead of `5` to represent an existing `id` in the test data.

**/ edit**

I have three MySQL tables for keeping localized page info:

```
CREATE TABLE `locale` (
  `languageCode` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `regionCode` char(3) NOT NULL default 'ZZ',
  `isActive` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL default 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`languageCode`,`regionCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parentId` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `FK_page_page_1` (`parentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_page_page_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `page` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `pageInfo` (
  `pageId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `languageCode` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `regionCode` char(3) NOT NULL default 'ZZ',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pageId`,`languageCode`,`regionCode`),
  KEY `FK_pageInfo_locale_1` (`languageCode`,`regionCode`),
  KEY `FK_pageInfo_page_1` (`pageId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_pageInfo_locale_1` FOREIGN KEY (`languageCode`, `regionCode`) REFERENCES `locale` (`languageCode`, `regionCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_pageInfo_page_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pageId`) REFERENCES `page` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is some test data:

```
/* locale */
INSERT INTO `locale` (languageCode,regionCode,isActive) VALUES ('de','ZZ','yes');
INSERT INTO `locale` (languageCode,regionCode,isActive) VALUES ('en','ZZ','yes');
INSERT INTO `locale` (languageCode,regionCode,isActive) VALUES ('nl','ZZ','yes');
/* page */
INSERT INTO `page` (id,parentId) VALUES (1,NULL);
INSERT INTO `page` (id,parentId) VALUES (2,1);
/* pageInfo */
INSERT INTO `pageInfo` (pageId,languageCode,regionCode) VALUES (1,'de','ZZ');
INSERT INTO `pageInfo` (pageId,languageCode,regionCode) VALUES (1,'en','ZZ');
INSERT INTO `pageInfo` (pageId,languageCode,regionCode) VALUES (1,'nl','ZZ');
INSERT INTO `pageInfo` (pageId,languageCode,regionCode) VALUES (2,'en','ZZ');
INSERT INTO `pageInfo` (pageId,languageCode,regionCode) VALUES (2,'nl','ZZ');
```

**The dilemma:**
To retrieve pages with `id 2` of all active locales I issue the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
        p.*,   pi.languageCode,   pi.regionCode
    FROM
        page AS p
        INNER JOIN pageInfo AS pi
            ON pi.pageId = p.id
        INNER JOIN locale AS l
            ON l.languageCode = pi.languageCode AND l.regionCode = pi.regionCode
    WHERE
        (p.id = '2')
        AND (l.isActive = 'yes')
```

How would I alter this statement, so that, when `id 2` is not available for a particular locale, it automatically falls back on the root page for that locale (that is: where `page.parentId IS NULL`)? My goal is to have MySQL give me either one, but not both, for the active locales.

I tried:

```
WHERE
    (p.id = '2' OR (p.parentId IS NULL))
```

But, of course, that gives me two records for locales that actually have `id 2` also. I'm pretty sure it's possible (either with `UNION`, sub selects, or a duplicate join on page) but I'm having a total SQL writers block here. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Whats if the parent page is also not available for the particular locale?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: good question! But just assume the root page (where `parentId IS NULL`, i.e. not necessarily the parent page) will always be available in the system. It's a page that can't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How about XOR? "one or the other but not both":

```
WHERE
    (p.id = '5' XOR (p.parentId IS NULL))
                ^---here
```

Comment: No sorry, that still gives me both records per locale, if page with `id 5` is available for that locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOINs and join both tables twice. The second time you join them specifically for the case of `p.parentId IS NULL`.

In the SELECT list use IFNULLs. First arguments are for the `id` specified, second ones are the fallbacks, i.e. the values for the root page.

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    IFNULL(l.languageCode, lr.LanguageCode) AS languageCode,
    IFNULL(l.regionCode, lr.regionCode) AS regionCode
FROM
    page AS p
    LEFT JOIN pageInfo AS pi
        ON pi.pageId = p.id
    LEFT JOIN locale AS l
        ON l.languageCode = pi.languageCode AND l.regionCode = pi.regionCode
    LEFT JOIN pageInfo AS pir
        ON pir.pageId = p.id AND p.parentId IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN locale AS lr
        ON lr.languageCode = pir.languageCode AND lr.regionCode = pir.regionCode
WHERE
    (p.id = '5' AND l.isActive = 'yes')
    OR (p.parentId IS NULL AND lr.isActive = 'yes')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second join predicate be `ON pir.pageId = p.parentId AND p.parentId IS NULL` to get the **parent** page for fallback?

Comment: @Andriy M: Sounded like a good plan. :) But unfortunately it still only returns the rows with `id 5`. You think doing different `JOIN` s might work? I tried various `RIGHT JOIN` s with your suggestions already, but to no avail. I also moved the `p.id = 5` to the `LEFT JOIN pi` and combined it with `WHERE (l.isActive = 'yes' OR lr.isActive = 'yes')`. That last tinkering returned all root pages again. Not just the one for which `id 5` is missing. :( Ugghh, I hate SQL so much sometimes.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: No, I'm trying to get the root page. That is the page which has its `parentId` set to `NULL`. But the `pageInfo` table should join on the `id` of that root page, not the `parentId`.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Forgot to add additional filter to WHERE. Take a look now, please.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: I don't believe it should. If `p.parentId IS NULL` you can hardly expect it to be at the same time equal to whatever `pir.pageId`, can you.

Comment: @andriy-m I understood the question wrong. See the reply from the OP.

Comment: @Andriy M: Thanks, I appreciate the effort. Unfortunately I tried that already too. If you feel like it: I've updated the question with the actual `CREATE` statements and some test data. So far all my efforts (including your latest suggestion) return multiple rows for the locales that don't have the `id`. I'm aiming for either one or the other. Right now, I'm filtering the results with PHP after the query, but I'ld love to do it in one go with MySQL.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Messed up with the WHERE conditions again. I think it should work now.

Comment: @Andriy M: Sorry, but it still gives me to many rows. :) It's proving to be a tougher nut to crack than I thought. I've spent hours trying myself already too. :-/ Although I must admit, writing SQL is not my best quality.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Seems like I'm going to have to agree with you about this problem being harder than it looks. Although I would probably prefer to have been stupidly and shamefully mistaken somewhere about my solution. The problem *does* seem deceptively easy...

Answer (score 0):

You could order by p.id=5 and use a limit of 1.  It's a bit of a hack, but it'll work.

```
SELECT 
        p.*,   pi.languageCode,   pi.regionCode
    FROM
        page AS p
        INNER JOIN pageInfo AS pi
            ON pi.pageId = p.id
        INNER JOIN locale AS l
            ON l.languageCode = pi.languageCode AND l.regionCode = pi.regionCode
    WHERE
        (p.id = '5' OR (p.parentId IS NULL))
        AND (l.isActive = 'yes')
    ORDER BY p.id = '5' DESC
    LIMIT 1
```